# Iterating over urls fails to find correct href in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am iterating through the website in the code. The following is what my code does. Loops through the 52 pages and gets the link to each URLs.

Then it iterates through those URLs and tries to get the link for the English Translation. if you see the Mongolian website, it has a section "Орчуулга" on the top right and it has "English" underneath - that is the link to the English translation.

However, my code fails to grab the link for the english translation and gives a wrong url.
Below is a sample output for the first article.

```
1
{'https://mn.usembassy.gov/mn/2020-naadam-mn/': 'https://mn.usembassy.gov/mn/sitemap-mn/'}
```

The expected output for the first page should be

```
1
{'https://mn.usembassy.gov/mn/2020-naadam-mn/': 'https://mn.usembassy.gov/2020-naadam/'}
```

Below is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://mn.usembassy.gov/mn/news-events-mn/page/{page}/'

urls = []
for page in range(1, 53):
    print(str(page) + "/52")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page)).content, 'html.parser')
    for h in soup.find_all('h2'):
        a = h.find('a')
        urls.append(a.attrs['href'])

print(urls)

i = 0
bilingual_dict = {}
for url in urls:
    i += 1
    print(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=url)).content, 'html.parser')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='translations_sidebar'):
        for ul in soup.find_all('ul'):
            for li in ul.find_all('li'):
                a = li.find('a')
    bilingual_dict[url] = a['href']
    print(bilingual_dict)
print(bilingual_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will print link to english translation:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://mn.usembassy.gov/mn/2020-naadam-mn/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

link = soup.select_one('a[hreflang="en"]')
print(link['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://mn.usembassy.gov/2020-naadam/
```

---

Complete code: (Where there isn't link to english translation, the value is set to `None`)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://mn.usembassy.gov/mn/news-events-mn/page/{page}/'

urls = []
for page in range(1, 53):
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page)).content, 'html.parser')
    for h in soup.find_all('h2'):
        a = h.find('a')
        urls.append(a.attrs['href'])

pprint(urls)

bilingual_dict = {}
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    link = soup.select_one('a[hreflang="en"]')
    bilingual_dict[url] = link['href'] if link else None

pprint(bilingual_dict)
```